# Dynamic SQL Pivot Query without Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am setting up a simple database to audit backups. Users from specific positions will "sign-off" on the audit to confirm that the system is needed and retention is correct. For now I will only have two positions doing sign-offs but in the future several more positions will be included hence my need to pull dynamically. I can't seem to figure out how to get a summary of what items in the audit have been signed off by each position. I attempted to use a pivot but I don't need an aggregate so I wasn't able to get it working.

I used the follow query to get a list of the things I want to display but I can't seem to combine them properly.

```
select BA.ID, A.Audit_Date, BA.Server_Name, BA.Group_Name, BA.Backup_Retention, BA.Backup_Type
from Backup_Audit BA
left join Audit A on BA.Audit_ID=A.ID
order by A.Audit_Date asc

select BS.Backup_Audit_ID,SP.SPDescription,ST.STDescription
from Backup_Signoff BS
inner join Signoff S on BS.Signoff_ID=S.ID
inner join Signoff_Position SP on S.Signoff_Position_ID=SP.ID
inner join Signoff_Type ST on BS.Signoff_Type_ID=ST.ID
```

Results:

```
ID          Audit Date             Server Name                    Group Name                     Backup_Retention     Backup Type
----------- ---------------------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------------------- --------------------
1           2016-05-12 19:03:59    server1                        NDMP_DD                        6 Months             NDMP
2           2016-05-12 19:03:59    server2                        Windows_DD                     1 Month              OS
4           2016-05-12 19:03:59    server3                        SQL_DD                         3 Months             SQL
3           2016-05-12 19:03:59    server3                        Windows_DD                     1 Month              OS
5           2016-05-12 19:03:59    server4                        SQL_DD                         3 Months             SQL
6           2016-05-12 19:05:59    server1                        NDMP_DD                        6 Months             NDMP
7           2016-05-12 19:05:59    server2                        Windows_DD                     1 Month              OS
9           2016-05-12 19:05:59    server3                        SQL_DD                         3 Months             SQL
8           2016-05-12 19:05:59    server3                        Windows_DD                     1 Month              OS

(9 row(s) affected)

Backup_Audit_ID SPDescription                  STDescription
--------------- ------------------------------ --------------------
1               Local IT                       Accepted
1               Controller                     Accepted
2               Local IT                       Not Accepted

(3 row(s) affected)
```

I would like to have the final product display as follows:

```
ID  Audit Date           Server Name  Group Name   Backup_Retention  Backup Type  Local IT      Controller
--- -------------------- ------------ ------------ ----------------- ------------ ------------- -----------
1   2016-05-12 14:20:10  server1      NDMP_DD      6 Months          NDMP         Accepted      Accepted
2   2016-05-12 14:20:10  server2      Windows_DD   1 Month           OS           Rejected      NULL
4   2016-05-12 14:20:10  server3      SQL_DD       3 Months          SQL          NULL          NULL
3   2016-05-12 14:20:10  server3      Windows_DD   1 Month           OS           NULL          NULL
5   2016-05-12 14:20:10  server4      SQL_DD       3 Months          SQL          NULL          NULL
6   2016-05-12 14:22:10  server1      NDMP_DD      6 Months          NDMP         NULL          NULL
7   2016-05-12 14:22:10  server2      Windows_DD   1 Month           OS           NULL          NULL
9   2016-05-12 14:22:10  server3      SQL_DD       3 Months          SQL          NULL          NULL
8   2016-05-12 14:22:10  server3      Windows_DD   1 Month           OS           NULL          NULL
```

Any help that anyone could provide would help greatly. When I get home I can upload scripts to build the DB and populate data, if it is needed. I have a feeling the result is easy to get to, just over my head currently. Thanks again.

Links to dml and ddl
[Create DB](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2riyn3e91o7uei0/help-create.sql?dl=0)
[Populate some data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48alfb8v5gepfcz/help-populate.sql?dl=0)

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? Those screen shots look eerily like sql 2000. If you could upload dml and ddl that would be a huge help. This appears to be a basic conditional aggregation but it is hard to figure out what you are really trying to do with pictures.

Comment: " I attempted to use a pivot but I don't need an aggregate". Looks like your data contain exactly  one Local IT "sign-off"  and one  Controller "sign-off"  for a given ID. So - don't panic. Use arbitrary MAX / MIN in PIVOT and see the result.

Comment: it was actually SQL 2008 R2. I uploaded the dml and ddl. I had to remove the pics so ill add txt output instead.

Comment: The question of course is why do you want to do 'presentation' logic inside SQL? Who is looking at this report? Where does the report go?

Comment: I think you are looking at some form of Dynamic SQL to get the last 2 columns to appear, and ensure that positions will automatically appear as new columns when added. I have worked on similar problems before: used dynamic SQL to achive the result you are looking for. This is not a small script and requires some time to get working. As @Nick.McDermaid said, you better do those manipulations in some report presentation tool. I use Excel's pivot tables a lot for quick and easy reporting.